# pagination widget: always on page 1 when returning to list view from edit or show

Tags: pagination, widget, typo3, overriding, fluid

When changing from a page >1 in the list-view of the paginator to e. g. the show-view and returning to the vist-view, always page 1 is been shown. 
This is not very handy, if you were on page 1432 before!

I know it's not the job of a paginator to save some states like the current page I was on before switching to another view. In other cases like a search word I store it in a session and restore it if not set. But this does not help in this case because I can only assign a variable to my list-view, not to the template of the pagination.

How can I solve this? The simple way would be to override [@widget_0][currentpage]. But that is not possible with standard methods because [@widget_0] is a subrequest, handeled only by the core.

My actual solution would be to extend the pagination widget class and write a method setCurrentPage(). Or to write my own paginator at all.

Thx for any help
Harald

Comment: I am currently look for a solution to this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `javascript:history.back();`?